# Are there any strategies for farming Treasure Rooms?

Tags: dungeon-boss

In Dungeon Boss there are numerous ways to unlock champions, one of them is only from the chests in treasure rooms. Is there a way to farm these apparently random rooms more effectively? Do they appear in boss levels more often? Higher level dungeons? Anything? Or are they completely random in nature?